SCD Type 2 Issue
I am trying to implement SCD Type 2 with Delta Lake implementation. I am trying to use the following code, however, it's not working as expected.
I have AssetId as my primary key (or merge condition). I was able to close or mark a record as inactive when the AssetName changes, however, I am not able to insert the New Record with the updated AssetName.
Has anybody faced this challenge?
Here is the code
output_columns = ['AssetId', 'AssetName', 'AssetCode']
merge_condition = 'AssetId'

merge_builder = target_table.alias("target").merge(
    source=source_df.alias("source"),
    condition=f"target.{merge_condition} = source.{merge_condition}"
)


# Update matched records: Mark old records as inactive
merge_builder = merge_builder.whenMatchedUpdate(
    condition="target.is_current = true AND (" +
              " OR ".join([f"target.{col} != source.{col}" for col in output_columns]) +
              ")",
   set={
        "is_current": lit(False),
        "end_date": current_timestamp()
    }
)

#Insert unmatched records: Add new rows for changes or new entries
insert_expr = {col : f"source.{col}" for col in output_columns}

insert_expr.update({
   "is_current": lit(True),
    "effective_date": current_timestamp(),
    "end_date": lit(None)
})


merge_builder = merge_builder.whenNotMatchedInsert(values=insert_expr)

#Execute the merge
merge_builder.execute()


Do you see any ERROR?

There is no error.

Show input and exp output for all.

I wrote some function long back. Here I tried to customize it for this question.
It has no is_current. Instead it uses effective_end_time IS null for same purpose.
Add test data to your post if you have trouble.
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from delta import DeltaTable

target_table = DeltaTable.forName('target_delta_table')
output_columns = ['AssetId', 'AssetName', 'AssetCode']
merge_condition = 'AssetId'


def scd_type_2_merge(df_new: DataFrame):
    """
    Performs an SCD Type 2 merge from df_new to target_table
    """

    df_new = df_new.withColumn('effective_start_time', F.lit(datetime.now()))
    attrs_are_different = ' OR '.join([f'NOT updates.{a} <=> target.{a}' for a in output_columns])

    # End Of Life rows (new versions of existing rows, so existing rows reach eol)
    df_eol = (
        df_new.alias('updates')
        .join(target_table.toDF().alias('target'), f'{merge_condition}')
        .where(f'target.effective_end_time IS null AND ({attrs_are_different})')
        .selectExpr('updates.*')
    )

    # union() resolves columns by order not name. So two tables being union'ed must have
    # same column order or the data will get misplaced.
    union_col_order = df_eol.selectExpr('NULL as mergeKey', '*').columns
    staged_updates = (
        # Rows whose effective_end_time be updated in the whenNotMatched clause
        df_eol.selectExpr('NULL as mergeKey', '*').select(union_col_order)
        # Rows that are new or will update the changed attributes in whenMatchedUpdate clause
        .union(df_new.selectExpr(f'{merge_condition} as mergeKey', '*').select(union_col_order))
    )

    # Newly added rows
    insert_mapping = {
        f'{merge_condition}': f'updates.{merge_condition}',
        'effective_start_time': 'updates.effective_start_time',
        'effective_end_time': 'null',
    }
    insert_mapping.update({attr_col: f'updates.{attr_col}' for attr_col in output_columns})

    # SCD merge
    target_table.alias('target').merge(
        staged_updates.alias('updates'), f'target.{merge_condition} = mergeKey'
    ).whenMatchedUpdate(
        # compare attrs for idempotency
        condition=f'target.effective_end_time IS null AND ({attrs_are_different})',
        set={'effective_end_time': 'updates.effective_start_time'},
    ).whenNotMatchedInsert(
        values=insert_mapping
    ).execute()



Thanks, let me check and get back to you.

As you mentioned you want to implement the SCD type 2 and you are facing the issue while inserting
I have tried the below aproach:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType, BooleanType
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, current_timestamp
from delta.tables import DeltaTable
target_schema = StructType([
    StructField("AssetId", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("AssetName", StringType(), False),
    StructField("AssetCode", StringType(), False),
    StructField("is_current", BooleanType(), False),
    StructField("effective_date", StringType(), False),
    StructField("end_date", StringType(), True)
])
source_schema = StructType([
    StructField("AssetId", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("AssetName", StringType(), False),
    StructField("AssetCode", StringType(), False)
])
source_df = spark.createDataFrame(source_data, source_schema)
target_table_path = "/delta/target_table"
target_df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save(target_table_path)
delta_target_table = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, target_table_path)
output_columns = ['AssetId', 'AssetName', 'AssetCode']
merge_condition = 'AssetId'
merge_builder = delta_target_table.alias("target").merge(
    source=source_df.alias("source"),
    condition=f"target.{merge_condition} = source.{merge_condition}"
)
merge_builder = merge_builder.whenMatchedUpdate(
    condition="target.is_current = true AND (" +
              " OR ".join([f"target.{col} != source.{col}" for col in output_columns]) +
              ")",
    set={
        "is_current": lit(False),
        "end_date": current_timestamp()
    }
)
merge_builder = merge_builder.whenNotMatchedInsert(
    values={
        "AssetId": "source.AssetId",
        "AssetName": "source.AssetName",
        "AssetCode": "source.AssetCode",
        "is_current": lit(True),
        "effective_date": current_timestamp(),
        "end_date": lit(None)
    }
)
merge_builder.execute()
updated_target_df = spark.read.format("delta").load(target_table_path)
updated_target_df.show()

In the above codedefining schema for target table
defining  schema for source dataframe
Updating matched records marking old records as inactive
Inserting unmatched records add new rows for changes or new entries
Results:

+-------+---------+---------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
|AssetId|AssetName|AssetCode|is_current|      effective_date|            end_date|
+-------+---------+---------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
|      1|   AssetA|    CodeA|      true|          2023-01-01|                null|
|      2|   AssetB|    CodeB|     false|          2023-01-01|2024-12-30 11:59:...|
|      4|   AssetD|    CodeD|      true|2024-12-30 11:59:...|                null|
|      3|   AssetC|    CodeC|      true|          2023-01-01|                null|
+-------+---------+---------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+



Thanks, however  lets says AssetB name has been changed as AssetB1 for AssetId =2, then  with the above code,  then the new record(with AssetB1, with AssetId = 2 is not getting inserted.)

ok let me retry and update the solution for you
